# Changing color attributes of android floating text label

Tags: android

I am facing hard time in changing the color attributes of Floating text Label
My XML Code looks  like this:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Base"
        android:id="@+id/input_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar_first_login"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText

            android:id="@+id/edit_input_name"
            android:textColorHint="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/name" />
 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

My Styles.XML looks like this:

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

I want to change the text color, hint text color, edit box Line color when not selected and edit box line color when selected.
I am unable to change colors.

Comment: Set the hint on TextInputLayout and remove it from EditText.

Comment: Do not modify android:textColor in your theme. Maybe you wanted to change android:textColorPrimary?

Comment: your first suggestion did not helped but your second suggestion helped.. I am still wondering about ...how to change edit box Line color when not selected  and all.. where to find those details

Comment: You need to apply android:theme to the EditText. Its going to be a 'Theme Overlay', its parent may be empty and you can override colorControlNormal (the default color) and colorControlActivated (color when selected).